# JavaScript "is not a function" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

What I'm trying to do is to disconnect selection, and the cancellation of some of the hot keys (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)

My code looks like that.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.ctrl = function(key, callback) {
        if(typeof key != 'object') key = [key];
        callback = callback || function(){
            return false;
        }
        return $(this).keydown(function(e) {
            var ret = true;
            $.each(key,function(i,k){
                if(e.keyCode == k.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) && e.ctrlKey) {
                    ret = callback(e);
                }
            });
            return ret;
        });
    };


    $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
        $(window).ctrl(['a','s','c']);
        return this.each(function() {           
            $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on')
            .css({
                '-moz-user-select':'none',
                '-o-user-select':'none',
                '-khtml-user-select':'none',
                '-webkit-user-select':'none',
                '-ms-user-select':'none',
                'user-select':'none'
            })
            .each(function() {
                $(this).attr('unselectable','on')
                .bind('selectstart',function(){
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':not(input,select,textarea)').disableSelection(); <== ERROOR
    $("#navigation").treeview({
        persist: "location",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I open page on Firefox, getting following error message on firebug

```
$(":not(input,select,textarea)").disableSelection is not a function
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions? Thx in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to pass jQuery to your function (in order to execute it!):

```
(function($){

    $.fn.ctrl = function(key, callback) { ... }

    $.fn.disableSelection = function() { ... }

})(jQuery); // <--- you forgot this!
```

Comment: don't get, where is the problem?

Comment: @Neal: Shouldn't your post say - "You forgot to attach (jQuery) at the end". Coz he is already passing  '$'

Comment: No. The function has the argument `$`, but unless you **pass** something to a function call, $ is undefined -- not a function.

Answer (score 4):

```
(function($){
   ...
});
```

That's nice, a [IEFE-closure](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) never executed (should be called NEFE :-) ). Call it by appending brackets, and pass arguments in between them (e.g. `...(jQuery)`) to the [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). Or leave the whole function away, in your case you don't need the closure at all.

BTW, you should never try to make your page unusable - users will run away from it. And don't forget that trying to make content uncopyable never prevents the content from being copied.

Comment: Without anything in the way of explanation, IMO this is a comment.

Comment: @Chris, Imediately Executing Function Expression is never executed, that's the correct answer.

Comment: I understand that, however, simple calling it a "NEFE" is hardly useful to someone who, clearly, does not understand. The goal here is to arrive at an answer -- a useful solution for the stated problem. Throwing out smiley faces and acronyms is not a useful solution.

Comment: @Chris: OK, that depends on the OP's knowledge. Such an error (the NEFE even doesn't throw anything) can be hard to spot after hours of work - if he knows the pattern, my answer would be enough. For those who don't, I now have added some links.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the answer -- I've removed my downvote.